# Redirect with angularJs - but only inside div/main element

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I have an html page with a header, main and footer (I use materialize and angularJS). I always want the header and footer to remain the same, but when I press links in the sidenav I want the main element to be another html page. Let's say I press the info link in the sidenav, I want the header and footer to remain, but I move from the main part of the html to another page. This is what I have so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1.0"/>
  <title>MyPage</title>
  <!-- CSS  -->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="css/materialize.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen,projection"/>
  <link href="css/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen,projection"/>
</head>

<body  ng-app="myPage" ng-controller="mainCtrl">
  <header>
    <ul id="sidenav" class="side-nav fixed light-blue lighten-1">
      <li><a id="page" class="white-text text-accent-1" href="#">Home</a> </li>
      <br/><br/>
      <li><a id="page1" class="white-text text-accent-1" href="#"><b>Info</b></a></li>
      <li><a id="page2" class="white-text text-accent-1" href="#"><b>Another page</b></a></li>
      <li><a id="page3" class="white-text text-accent-1" href="#"><b>Even one more page</b></a></li>
    </ul>
  </header>

  <main>
    <div id="main">
        <p> Some text for main page here </p>
     </div>
  </main>

  <footer class="page-footer orange">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col l6 s12">
          <h5 class="white-text">About</h5>
          <p class="grey-text text-lighten-4">
            About my company.
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </footer>


  <!--  Scripts-->
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/materialize.js"></script>
  <script src="controllers/mainCtrl.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

This might be really easy, but I haven't found out how to be able to switch back and forth, and also keep the header and footer. I tried to just link the new html page into , but then I have to copy over the header and footer, which is not ideal. I don't want to have possibly 10-15 html pages I have to edit if I want to change the sidenav for example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to set up a router and put a `ng-view` directive on some of your html elements:

```
...
</header>
<div ng-view>
    <main>
       ...
    </main>
</div>
<footer class="page-footer orange">
...
```

simple routing example:

```
app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
      .when('/home', {
        templateUrl: 'home.html',
        controller: 'homeCtrl',
      );
}]);
```

If you than use your sidebar link

```
<a id="page" class="white-text text-accent-1" href="#/home">Home</a>
```

The routeProvider will load your `home.html` and `homeCtrl` between the defined element with the `ng-view` directive